# What is the computational complexity of k bit subset sum problem?

Tags: complexity-theory

The *k bit subset sum* problem is:

**Input:**

$(S, k, b)$ where $S$ is multi set of positive integers encoded in binary (base 2), $k$ is also positive integer encoded in binary (base 2) and $b$ is **bit** (binary digit) so that always $b\in\{0,1\}$.

**Output:**

**True** if exists subset sum of $S$ whose $k$ bit (binary digit) equals to $b$.

**False** if does not exist subset sum of $S$ whose $k$ bit (binary digit) equals to $b$.

Comment: Nice! How did you come up with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that when $k=1$, the $k$th bit is the LSB.

If $b = 0$ then the answer is always positive, since you can take the sum of the empty subset.

If $b = 1$ and one of the numbers has its $k$th bit equal to $1$ then the answer is positive, so we can assume that all $k$th bits are equal to $0$. Reduce all numbers modulo $2^k$. Since originally the $k$th bits were $0$, all numbers are less than $2^{k-1}$. If the sum of all numbers is less than $2^{k-1}$, then clearly the answer is negative. If the sum of all numbers is at least $2^{k-1}$, arrange them in some arbitrary order $x_1,x_2,\ldots$, and sum them one by one until reaching the first sum $s_i = x_1 + \cdots + x_i$ which is at least $2^{k-1}$. Since $s_{i-1} < 2^{k-1}$ and $x_i < 2^{k-1}$, we see that $s_i < 2^k$. Thus the $k$th bit of $s_i$ is $1$. Hence the answer is positive.

Summarizing, here is our algorithm:

- If $b = 0$, answer True.
- If $b = 1$ and there exists a number whose $k$th bit is $1$, answer True.
- If $b = 1$ and all $k$th bits are $0$, reduce the input modulo $2^k$, and answer True if the sum of all reduced numbers is at least $2^{k-1}$.

Comment: Nice solution. I have the feeling there's also a polynomial algorithm if we demand that the sum is $\geq 2^k$ when $b=0$, but I can't find it.